# Microsoft Graph - Convert Read Emails

Tags: c#, graph, console-application, microsoft-graph-api

I was able to get all my emails using Microsoft Graph, but I am having to find a solution to get the information in a more visual way using a Console App. I cannot find a way to do that.

Code I currently have:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    var tenantId = "";
    var clientId = "";
    var clientSecret = "";

    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

    IUserMessagesCollectionPage msgs = await graphClient.Users["my email"].Messages.Request().GetAsync();

    List<Message> messages = new List<Message>();
    messages.AddRange(msgs.CurrentPage);
    while (msgs.NextPageRequest != null)
    {
        msgs = await msgs.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
        messages.AddRange(msgs.CurrentPage);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I can list all my messages, but not actually convert it in a easy way to read.

Comment: If i am not wrong , you are trying to print your mail on console? could you please help me to understand , thanks

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new(await GraphAuthAsync());
        IUserMessagesCollectionPage graphRequest = await graphClient.Me.Messages
            .Request()
            .Filter("isRead eq false")
            .Expand("attachments")
            .Top(10)
            .Select("id,from")
            .GetAsync();
```

so, the property byte is missing.